# G Suite Marketplace SDK: The form cannot be saved

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

Sorry for asking this silly question but Google Marketplace SDK UI cannot provide any help with its own form - the configuration form.

I cannot save the form, because it wants something but doesn't say what exactly. I filled out all the Required fields, but it's insisting I need something else - but what?

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: I don't see a script version.  The input field directly under the check box. "Sheets add-on script version"  In the code editor, click the "File" menu and then "Manage Versions"  If you don't have a version, then you need to "Save a New Version"  Whenever you publish the add-on, you need to go into "Manage Versions" and create a new version.  Even if you've saved the Apps Script file, you are still using the old version.  If you republish with the same version, there will be no difference in your add-on.

Comment: I actually did try to provide script version. Sorry for adding screenshot which doesn't reflect this. I'll try to update it if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are missing the field corresponding to the script version.

As specified in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons#step_1_create_a_script_version), in order to publish an editor add-on you should first [create a version of your add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions#creating_a_version), because the add-on needs to use a specific version of your project.

To do that, go to `File > Manage Versions...` in your script editor, and then click `Save new version`.

Once the version is saved, write the version number in the corresponding field in the configuration form (placeholder is `Sheets add-on script version`).

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Unfortunately no, of course I tried to provide the script version (it is "0.0.1" in my case). Sorry for my silly screenshot.

Comment: @Onkeltem in such case, can you provide a screenshot of the behaviour you are actually getting?

Comment: @Onkeltem I don't think a  version number can be "0.0.1". It [has to be a number](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.versions/create#request-body). Are you sure that's your version number?

Comment: Oh my god, it allowed me to save it and so I reasoned it was ok :) I just opened the "Manage version" dialog and see that the version is actualy 1 (one) and "0.0.1" was put into the Description field. Let me try it now.

Comment: Nah, that didn't work. Here is my version dialog: https://nimb.ws/E5p98o But something else DID work! It's weird but once I pasted "Terms of service URL" (thought I don't have any so I pasted a random URL) the Save button has been activated. This is all so silly... and I'm ashemed of using Stackoverflow for this nonsense.